# Data Filtering, Data Sorting, and Pagination securely in one function

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting, pagination, filtering

## The Goal:

In essence, I'm displaying an array of objects (data retrieved from MySQL). I'm currently working on the functionality of being able to Filter and Sort this data upon the user's interaction. The pagination aspect has already been solved. But I feel like I may be over complicating the integration.

When the user clicks on a Table Header, that needs to reload the page with the data being sorted in ascending order. If the user clicks the same Table Header, the page needs to reload again with the data being sorted in descending order.

The user also has a dropdown box and an input field to search for specific data in specific columns.

Now the big problem that I'm having is integrating this all into one function without making the url insane.

Here's the current function I have:

```
public function tp1s($page = 0, $column = null, $filter = null)
    {
        $data['location'] = 'tp1s';
        //Pagination Config
        $config['base_url'] = 'admin/tp1s';
        $config['per_page'] = 19;

        //Check if filters are in place
        if (isset($column) && isset($filter)) {
            $totalRows = /*Model that returns total number of rows based on filter selection*/
            $config['base_url'] = base_url('admin/tp1s/' . $column . '/' . $filter);
            $dataStart = /*Model that returns table data that the user will see. It only returns data that matches up with the filtering. It is offset and limited based on $page and $config['per_page']*/
        } else {
            $totalRows = /*Model that returns number of rows with no filtering*/
            $dataStart = /*Model that returns all table data that the user will see. It is offset and limited based on $page and $config['per_page']*/
        }

        //Pagination
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['total_rows'] = $totalRows;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        //Get TP1s
        $data['data']['tp1s'] = $dataStart;

        //Get schools (This little section is not important)
        $data['schools'] = $this->Admin->getTableList('schools');
        foreach($data['schools'] as $school){
            preg_match_all('/[A-Z]/', $school->name, $abrev);
            $abrev = implode($abrev[0]);
            $school->name = $school->zip.'-'.$abrev;
        }

        //Set variable for view then load the view
        $data['path'] = 'panels/admin/tp1s';
        $this->load->view('pages/admin', $data);
    }
```

The url displays as `https://site/admin/tp1s` when there are no filters or pagination
The url displays as `https://site/admin/tp1s/column/filter` when there is a filter and no pagination.
Any pagination shows up at the end of the url.

Now my problem is figuring out how to implement sorting into this as well. I wanted to use AJAX for all of this but there is sensitive data being displayed and I don't want to create a controller that echo's sensitive data.

**The Big Hold Up**

I could solve this very easily by allowing the url to pass 2 more variables for the sorting to use. But I really want to avoid that. At that point the url would look very sloppy. For now, it's gonna be what I have to go with. Again I would typically just use Ajax to go retrieve the data while passing some variables that the controller could use. However I'm pretty certain it's possible for people to view the data by going straight to the controller because the data would be echo'd. So that's not an option because there is sensitive data.

## Update

So the only "solution" that I've come up with is to use URL Queries (Which I didn't even know you could use with CodeIgniter while still using URL Segments). This doesn't really solve my problem. The URL still looks a little jumbled. However, it at least has that *"I'm being used by the program"* look. I did my best to summarize the code in the comments for those who aren't feeling the need to read all of this:

```
public function tp1s($page = 0){
    $queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; //Get query string to pass on to the pagination

    //Some Pagination config that my code will use
    $config['base_url'] = base_url('admin/tp1s');
    $config['per_page'] = 18;

    $tableData = $this->Model->getThatData() //Get rows from table in database

    //Check if filters are in place
    if (isset($_GET['filter']) && isset($_GET['column'])) {
        //Get url query variables and set PHP variables
        $column = $_GET['column'];
        $filter = $_GET['filter'];
        $tableData = filterArray($tableData, $column, $filter); //Helper that filters data
    }

    //Check if sorting is in place
    if(isset($_GET['sort']) && isset($_GET['by']) && isset($_GET['type'])){
        //Get url query variables and set PHP variables
        $sort = $_GET['sort'];
        $by = $_GET['by'];
        $type = $_GET['type'];

        //Other functions within the helper that sort the data
        if($by == 'ascending'){
            $tableData = sortAscending($tableData, $sort, $type);
        }elseif($by == 'descending'){
            $tableData = sortDescending($tableData, $sort, $type);
        }
    }

    //Some Pagination Config
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['reuse_query_string'] = true;
    $config['total_rows'] = count($tableData);
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    //Selects correct section of sorted and filtered data that should be presented to the user according to the Pagination
    $tableData = array_slice($tableData, $page, $config['per_page']);

    /*
    Some unimportant code that loads the view and stuff
    */
}
```